# Ignorar arquivos de unit test utilizando jest e webpack

Tags: webpack, jest

Fala galera, estou com um dificuldade de ignorar meus arquivos de testes quando foi buildar minha aplicação. Como configuro o Web Pack para ignorar os arquivos de testes?

Answer (score 0):

No seu script de build no arquivo package.json insira a opção --ignore, por exemplo:

```
babel / --out-dir dist --ignore *.spec.js --copy-files
```